# 'The server is unwilling to process the request' when adding User to Group ADirectory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

The problem I have happens with one AD and doesn't happen on another(Just works)

Exception at group.Invoke

Code:

```
root = new DirectoryEntry("ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root))
        {
            searcher.Filter = "(&(objectcategory=group)(name=" + GroupName + "))";
            using (DirectoryEntry group = searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry())
            {
                searcher.Filter = "(&(SAMAccountName=" + PersonName + "))";
                using (DirectoryEntry user = searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    group.Invoke("Add", user.Path);
                }
            }
        }
        RefreshList();
    }
```

Is there a reason for that?

Edit:
[image: Error]

[image: More details for error]

Comment: Can you please post the full and exact exception (including any `.InnerException` values) that you're getting?

Comment: Is the user you are trying to add already a member?

Comment: @Damien No, and I tried using credentials for account that is capable of replicating the results using outlook.

Comment: Maybe you could use this: group.Invoke("Add", new Object[] {user.Path.ToString()});

Comment: @Damien Exact same error message :(